# How to change production environment to Development environment in Dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I was running an example for Dash in python.
For first It worked fine, then after 2-4 example it shows me this error.

> (dash) C:\Users\nayo9002\Desktop>python dash_app.py
>
> Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
>   Debugger PIN: 761-866-226
>
> - Serving Flask app "dash_app" (lazy loading)
> - Environment: production
>     WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
> - Debug mode: on
>
> Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
>   Debugger PIN: 288-266-928

I want to change this Production environment to Development. How should I proceed?

Comment: You don't need to change that to develop your `Dash` app. If you specify `debug=True` when you call `app.run_server()`, then your app will automatically reload when it detects changes to the code. It will still say the environment is production, but that won't hinder development.

Comment: Thanks. So, you mean whenever I change my code scripts it will automatically reflect on app(i.e. real time changes).

Comment: Yes. The page will reload and display your changes.

Answer (score 0):

In windows :

> FLASK_ENV=development

In Linux :

> export FLASK_ENV=development

Comment: Where do I enter this?

Comment: At CMD or whatever your prefers

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm a bit surprised. Is there also a way to use it as code so one wouldn't need to enter it manually(?) ?